# Creating data structures in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a problem where I have to convert a 2D array into a data structure that's efficient for printing out a table for a scheduler. The link to the problem is http://goo.gl/rRUsj [Opens in Google Docs].

First of all, just to clarify by your understanding, am I supposed write the code to generate the table itself? Or just write the code to create the structure?

Secondly, since I'm new to PHP, any ideas on how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first: You need a datababase. You have to learn how to make a database:

```
1:UML(Class) diagram
2:Relations(1 to 1, n to 1, n to m, ...)
3:Datatypes
4:Make the database in Open Office
```

Then you have to learn how to make the database in PHP.(`Arrays as tables, ...`)
I hope i help you!